# Output image data from HDMI port using C/C++/opencv on a windows 10 PC

Tags: c++, c, image, opencv, hdmi

I am working with a DMD (digital micromirror array) device Provided from TI (DLP3010EVM-LC). It is basically a projector that can be controlled through USB and HDMI. The HDMI is used to input external image data to the projector, thus the DMD. I am planning to control the pixels of the DMD by sending an image of 1-bit data. My goal framerate is about 1000 fps. It seems that this is possible in case of a 1-bit data where the pixel data even though HDMI port has a max of 60 fps. I am looking for a way to send image data using c/c++/opencv from my windows 10 PC HDMI output. I looked a lot on different sites and forums but couldn't find a concrete way or documentations of how to program the HDMI port (in fact, I just need image output with no sound data). Some people on the Rasberry Pi community simply use imshow() from opencv for this, but it doesn't seem to work on a Windows PC.

Any help on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Well how is the HDMI port hooked up on your computer? That's right, it's the screen. You're asking how to show pixels on the screen?

Comment: Are you planning on providing a link to your DMD so folk know what device you are referring to? Are you going to say what you were hoping to display - frame rate, dimensions?

Comment: For windows PC used cv2.CAP_DSHOW

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have edited my post. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @user253751 Yes. it is basically showing an image on an external screen. However, the data are 1-bit array to address each individual mirror on the DMD so I am not sure if this counts as showing an image or rather sending raw data through HDMI.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Windows does not understand the concept of "raw data through HDMI" - HDMI is a way to attach screens so you can see your windows. So the way to display some pixels through HDMI is to put a window on that screen. Unless it's changed recently.

Comment: Windows PC used MSMF. Here is [link]]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/audio-video-capture

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the electronics stackexchange

Comment: If you have an example using `imshow()` on a Raspberry Pi, or a link, please share that as a reference. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.